# Angular 7: cannot find the type definition file

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular7

Yesterday my project worked well but today I encounter an error after the installation of `ngx-pagination` module:

> ERROR in src/app/views/dashboard/step1/step1.component.ts(1,23): error
>   TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/googlemaps'.
>   src/app/views/dashboard/step1/step1.component.ts(187,34): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
>   src/app/views/dashboard/step1/step1.component.ts(190,29): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
>   src/app/views/dashboard/step1/step1.component.ts(193,26): error
>   TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.
>   src/app/views/job/quick-job-form/quick-job-form.component.ts(1,23):
>   error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for
>   '@types/googlemaps'.
>   src/app/views/job/quick-job-form/quick-job-form.component.ts(182,34):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
>   src/app/views/job/quick-job-form/quick-job-form.component.ts(188,29):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
>   src/app/views/job/quick-job-form/quick-job-form.component.ts(191,26):
>   error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.
>   src/app/views/job/quick-job-form/quick-job-form.component.ts(336,24):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.

Please help me.

Comment: How did you installed `ngx-pagination` ?

Comment: i run this command npm install ngx-pagination --save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using `@types/googlemaps` in your `step1.component.ts` file, and other files listed in the error.
Remove the utilisation of this component, or install it, with this command:

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

Comment: it will work, please reinstall @types/googlemaps this package

Answer (score 6):

This package is deprecated now, types for the Google Maps browser API have moved to @types/google.maps:

```
npm install --save @types/google.maps
```